# Powershell variable expansion when calling other programs

Tags: powershell, variable-expansion

I have a small problem trying to unzip a file using the [`7za`](http://7-zip.org/download.html)
command-line utility in Powershell.

I set the `$zip_source` variable to the zip file's path and the
`$unzip_destination` to the desired output folder.

However the command-line usage of `7za` needs arguments specified like this:

```
7za x -y <zip_file> -o<output_directory>
```

So my current call looks like this:

```
& '7za' x -y "$zip_source" -o$unzip_destination
```

Due to the fact that there can be no space between `-o` and the destination it
seems that PowerShell will not expand the `$unzip_destination` variable, whereas `$zip_source` is expanded.

Currently the program simply extracts all the files into the root of `C:\` in
a folder named `$unzip_destination`.
Setting different types of quotes around the variable won't work neither:

```
-o"$unzip_destination" : still extracts to C:\$unzip_destination
-o'$unzip_destination' : still extracts to C:\$unzip_destination
-o $unzip_destination  : Error: Incorrect command line
```

Is there any way to force an expansion before running the command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try like this:

```
-o $($unzip_destination)
```

<sup>Editor's note: This solution only works *with* a space after `-o` (in which case just `-o $unzip_destination` would do) - if you remove it, the command doesn't work as intended.

This approach is therefore not suitable for appending a variable value directly to an option name, as required by the OP.</sup>

Comment: There can be no space between -o and the unzip_destination

Comment: When I leave out the space after the -o that works - thanks. Does `$()` start some kind of subshell in PowerShell (sorry I am new to Windows scripting from a Unix-background).

Comment: $() is called a subexpression, and it causes everything inside the parenths to be returned as one value: $("Hello, " + "world!") returns literally: Hello, world!
These are useful when wanting the output of some expression to be translated to a string in the middle of another string.

Comment: Removing the space does _not_ work - unless you enclose the whole argument in `"..."`, but then you can just use jonZ's simpler answer. Good hint, @SpellingD; worth adding that, in the interest of robustness, `$(...)` as part of a string should always be used with explicit double-quoting, because with an unquoted token it doesn't always work - as is the case here, because the token starts with `-`; see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6467

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
& '7za' x -y "$zip_source" "-o$unzip_destination"
```

Comment: Works as well - I guess I should have kept on experimenting with quotes.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
& '7za' x -y $zip_source -o${unzip_destination}
```

Comment: Perhaps surprisingly, that would only work if the token didn't start with `-`.