# How do you expand a powershell variable as parameters to another program?

Tags: powershell, arguments

First I have tried to locate other questions and these all seem related to replacement rather than expansion.

- [How to expand variable in powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40915420/how-to-expand-variable-in-powershell)
- [Powershell variable expansion when calling other programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483960/powershell-variable-expansion-when-calling-other-programs)
- [Powershell variable expansion in parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13079674/powershell-variable-expansion-in-parameters)
- [How to expand a variable when calling another powershell instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45918183/how-to-expand-a-variable-when-calling-another-powershell-instance)

So I must first create clarity on what I mean by "expansion".

```
> $TEST="Foo Bar"
> echo foo bar
foo
bar
> echo $TEST
Foo Bar
```

When passing two parameters, powershell's implementation of echo will print each parameter on its own line.

If I echo a variable with two parameters it is passed as a single parameter. I would like the variable to be expanded into the multiple arguments which it contains, getting the behavior from the first instance.

I have looked at:

- Single quotes
- Parentheses
- Curly braces in different forms

Is this possible in powershell?

Context Update:

Unfortunately I'm not the one setting the variable, this comes from gitlab environment variables.

Comment: `echo (-split $TEST)` maybe? Another way: `echo $TEST.split()`

Comment: "If I echo a variable with two parameters" - the variable has no parameters - it just contains the 1 string that you created with `"Foo Bar"`. Try `$TEST = "Foo", "Bar"` in comparison

Comment: ```echo foo bar``` is an alias for ```Write-Output @("foo", "bar")``` - i.e. write out an array containing two strings, whereas ```echo $TEST``` is basically ```Write-Output "Foo Bar"``` - i.e. output a single string. If you do what @Mathias R. Jessen says you're setting  the variable ```$TEST``` to be an array of 2 strings so it'll output them on separate lines.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want the `@` [splat operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting):

```
$test = "foo","bar"
echo @test
```

This will have the exact same effect as `echo foo bar`

Answer (score 1):

> **How to pass a list of arguments into a powershell commandlet?**

Let's say you need to pass a bunch of CSV header fields into `-Header` argument, that is part of the `ConvertFrom-Csv` commandlet in order to convert an array into a CSV.

```bash
# The test array
$pac = @("app1", "app2")

# The needed command:
$pac | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header id, gui, src, sco, name, loc
# This works, but is too verbose, and can't be modified.

# So you Try-1:
$hdr = 'id,gui,src,sco,name,loc'
$pac | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header $hdr
# Not working!
```

**Q**: What is going on?
**A-1**: It's complicated, but solution is easy, once you find it.
**A-2**: There are 3 main solutions to skin this cat.

`Solution-1`
Write the header variable as a *string*, and use the `-split` operator inline.
**Caveats**: *Watch you spaces! And harder to read.*
**Advantage**: *Simple.*

```
$hdr = 'id,gui,src,sco,name,loc'
$pac | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header ($hdr -split ',')
```

`Solution-2`
Write the header variable as a *quoted list*.†
**Caveats**: *Still long and verbose.*
**Advantage**: *Easy to read.*
**†** <sub>I was never able to use the *splat* `@` operator here.</sub>

```
$hdr = 'id', 'gui', 'src', 'sco', 'name', 'loc'
$pac | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header $hdr
```

`Solution-3`
Write the header as a *tricky* [just my way to name it] argument function that only expands its arguments.
**Caveats**:   *Is tricky at first sight.*
**Advantage**: *No quotes and easy to read, and can be reused.*

```
function ql { $args }
$hdr = (ql id, gui, src, sco, name, loc)
$pac | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header $hdr
```